# JDK while running java program on eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse

I'm running a fairly simple java program that reads lines from a file one-by-one, does some processing via api calls, and then writes some output.  Everything runs swimmingly until about 10,000 or so lines into the file, the program stops running - in the error console I see this message:

> Message: JAXP00010001: The parser has encountered more than "64000" entity expansions in this document; this is the limit imposed by the JDK.

I've done [a little searching around](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.win.70.doc/diag/appendixes/cmdline/Djdkxmlmaxgeneralentitysizelimit.html) and found that you can adjust the JDK settings to solve this issue:

> -Djdk.xml.maxGeneralEntitySizeLimit=value

So, I placed this line in my eclipse.ini file and set the value to '0'.  Unfortunately the problem is not solved and I get the same error message.  Is eclipse.ini the wrong place to tweak the jdk settings?
Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running the program within Eclipse you need to open the 'Run > Run Configurations' menu and look in the 'Java Application' section for your program.

Select the 'Arguments' tab and put your setting in the 'VM arguments' section.

Click 'Apply' to save the setting

Comment: hmmmm - thanks greg but unfortunately that did not do the trick.  I've also read you can change your jaxp.properties but I don't see this on my system.  back to the drawing board!

Comment: update: +1 for Greg, -1 for me!  The correct argument needed is `-DentityExpansionLimit=1000000`